# How to modify existing <content> in a element?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I would like to extend the content and add new dom elements that contain data-binding. In the example runs the add new item, but data-binding does not work. Is it possible to solve my problem?

```
<polymer-element name="wizard">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: block;
            }

            :host #pages section {
                position: static;
            }

        </style>

        <core-animated-pages id="pages"
                             transitions="slide-from-right"
                             selected="{{selectedPageIndex}}">
            <content id="content"></content>
        </core-animated-pages>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            attached: function() {
                var nodes = this.$.content.getDistributedNodes();

                for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                    if(nodes[i] instanceof HTMLElement) {
                        var el = nodes[i].querySelector('div div');
                        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + '<button on-tap="{{nextPage}}">Next</button>';
                    }
                }
            },

            selectedPageIndex: 0,

            previousPage: function () {
                this.$.pages.selectPrevious(true);
            },

            nextPage: function () {
                this.$.pages.selectNext(true);
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Have you seen https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#boundhtml? I'm not sure that it will work with add bindings to light dom nodes though. You could make a copy of distributed nodes  though, run injectBoundHTML, and add them to a container in your SD.

Comment: Thanks for fast response, I'll try it.

Comment: @ebidel injectBoundHTML insert elements correctly. Also it is correctly bind the string data. Unfortunately, functions binding behaves strangely. When the function execute error occurs. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchMethod' of undefined`

Comment: @NILL It’s better to deal with `distributedNodes` on `domReady` event, not on `attached`. I guess changing the handler might do the trick.

Comment: @mudasobwa Tried your method. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the cause of your problem.

**TL;DNR**

Add

```
this.eventController = this;
```

line in the very beginning of your `domReady` handler. That *mystically* does the trick and event handlers become bound and handled.

---

I treat this as bug in current `Polymer` implementation and will report it to Polymer team. The cause of the problem is `findController` function in `polymer.js:10696` as by version `0.5.4`. When the dispatcher looks up for event handler, it iterates parents of event target until the one having `eventController` attribute defined. Unfortunately, this attribute is being handled properly for `lightFromTemplate` function *only*. When shadow DOM is bound with `injectBoundHTML`, this assignment is forgotten in the current implementation.

Live preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/67WwbKmqsJRmsdXCbgbb?p=preview

**NB** Please note that web-components *must* be named with hyphen inside. `my-wizard` is a proper name, while `wizard` is not.

Comment: Thank you for fast and detailed response.